error alert when using tinymce in a spring boot website
I am trying to use tinymce in my personal project.
But when I called it by textarea and an id, a alert display when i proceed to the page which embeded tinymce like this:
error image
here is my config in head tag:
<script th:src="@{https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/6.8.3/tinymce.min.js}"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce',
        plugins:[
            'advlist', 'link', 'lists', 'charmap', 'anchor', 'pagebreak',
            'wordcount', 'fullscreen', 'emoticons'
        ],
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustif | fullscreen | emoticons',
        menubar: 'edit format',
        content_style: 'body{font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px}'
    });
</script>

Thanks for your helps.
